# ReactJS: save state when navigate with browser button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app has two pages, first, the home page, which is a list of items, loaded with ajax, and support pagination. when you click an item in the list, it will render a new page, shows the detail of the item. I'm using `react-router` and it works fine.

However, when I press **back button**, I'll get back to the home page, and all the previous state is lost, I have to wait for ajax load again, and lost the pagination too.

So, how can I improve this, let the page act as an ordinary one (when you press back button you can return to the previous state instantly, even with the same scroll position), thanks.

Comment: If you have two actual HTML pages you're navigating, you'd need to rely on something like local storage, or use only web page.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I have only one HTML page

Comment: Where are you storing the state of your app? What is triggering the Ajax requests a second time?

Comment: @WiredPrairie click on a button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved this myself by providing a module `Store`, which is like this:

```
// Store.js

var o = {};

var Store = {
  saveProductList: function(state) {
    o['products'] = state;
  },
  getProductList: function() {
    return o['products'];
  }
};    

module.exports = Store;
```

then in the home page component, load and save the state:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var state = Store.getProductList();
  if (state) {
    this.setState(state);
  } else {
    // load data via ajax request
  }
},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
  Store.saveProductList(this.state);
}
```

this works for me.

Comment: I spent way to long unable to believe that react doesn't have a built in way to handle this. But as of this time this is the best solution without adding another dependency.

Answer (score -1):

You should use dynamic routes like this example:

```
<Route name="inbox" handler={Inbox}>
  <Route name="message" path=":messageId" handler={Message}/>
  <DefaultRoute handler={InboxStats}/>
</Route>
```

If you change the messageId(child component) you will still have the same state in the Inbox(parent) Component.

It will look something like this:

```
<Route name="search" path="/search/:query?/:limit?/:offset?" handler={Search} />
```